# Cors seems to be enabled on my node server by default. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

So I have a very basic node and express server as seen below. No middleware or anything, but I'm still able to log the response from axios made to google.com. Shouldn't this result in a cors error resulting in me having to use middleware or set the server up to make cross origin requests? Still unclear on CORS a little bit, any clarification is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var axios = require('axios');

app.on('listening', () => {
    axios.get('https://google.com')
    .then(response => console.log(response.data));
});

app.get('*', function(request, response){
  response.sendfile('./dist/index.html');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
      console.log(err.message);
  }
  next();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    app.emit('listening');
    console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

Comment: your server requesting to other server is not a cross origin request

Comment: To follow up on what @ArpitSolanki said, the cross-origin policy is a security feature for *web browsers*, computers can and do request resources from the internet via http all the time. Think about things like `curl`, `wget`, etc. Code that's running on your server doesn't have an 'origin', so a request to another resource can't be 'cross-origin'.

Answer (score 2):

CORS is a **browser** thing. It doesn't apply to server-side code (in Node, PHP, Java, ...). From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/):

> This document defines a mechanism to enable **client-side** cross-origin requests.

and later

> User agents commonly apply same-origin restrictions to network requests. These restrictions prevent a **client-side Web application** running from one origin from obtaining data retrieved from another origin, and also limit unsafe HTTP requests that can be automatically launched toward destinations that differ from the running application's origin.

*(my emphasis)*